# extract data with special value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, data-analysis

I have a dataset like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scientist':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.",
                             "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
               'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry",
                                "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology",
                                "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology",
                                "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"]})
```

I want to count the number of scientists in each subject field and extract subject fields that have more than 2 scientists. this is my code to count the number of scientists

```
 number_of_scientists_in_fields=data.groupby(['SubjectField'])['scientist'].count()
```

how can I extract subject fields that have more than 2 scientists?

Answer (score 2):

Use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), as follows:

```
fields = df.value_counts('SubjectField').to_frame('count')
res = fields[fields['count'] > 2]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                        count
SubjectField                 
Biomedical Engineering      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, which maybe is not as good as Dani's could be this:

```
> df2 = df[df.SubjectField.duplicated(keep=False)]
> df2.groupby('SubjectField').count()
                        scientist
SubjectField
Biomedical Engineering          4
```

This example however will include 2 or more (not > 2)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a `Series` and then filter it with `> 2`:

Use [`Groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
In [2554]: x = df.groupby('SubjectField')['scientist'].count()
In [2559]: ans = x[x > 2]

In [2560]: ans
Out[2560]: 
SubjectField
Biomedical Engineering    4
Name: scientist, dtype: int64
```

Comment: how can I delete subject fields that have less than 2 scientists, from my data?

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly delete the rows? Just pick the rows with count > 2, like in my answer.

Comment: I need to do some other manipulations of data so I need to drop some parts. this is not the real dataset though

Comment: I got it. What I am trying to say is, its the same thing to delete rows or pick the ones with count greater than 2.

Comment: you dont understand me.I need to use the rest of the data!

Comment: Would be better if you could post another question with sample data and expected output.